# Locate libclang.so on OSX10.10?

Tags: macos, vim, clang, llvm-clang

I'm trying to make my `YouCompleteMe` work which is a `vim` auto-completion plugin.

I use

`sudo find / -name "libclang.so" -print`

to locate my `libclang.so`. I got result

> find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
>   find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory

I'm wondering that **does that mean there is no `libclang.so` on my mac?**

After that I installed `llvm-clang` under my `~` directory following these commands:

```
cd ~/llvm-clang
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
cd llvm/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
cd ../..
cd llvm/tools/clang/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk extra
cd ../../../..
cd llvm/projects
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk compiler-rt
cd ../..
mkdir llvm-build
cd llvm-build/
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
make
```

Everything worked fine so far.
However, I ran

`sudo find / -name "libclang.so" -print`

I got the same result.

Anyway, I don't know if this helps to make the question more clear:

```
$ sudo find / -name "llvm" -print



find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/docs/llvm
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/include/llvm
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/share/llvm
/Users/yangyy/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/llvm
/Users/yangyy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/bindings/go/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/bindings/ocaml/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/bindings/python/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/include/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra/clang-tidy/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra/test/clang-tidy/Inputs/Headers/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/cmake/modules/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/include/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/lib/cmake/llvm
/Users/yangyy/llvm-clang/llvm-build/tools/clang/tools/extra/clang-tidy/llvm
/usr/share/file/magic/llvm
```

Where is the `libclang.so`?

Why there is no `libclang.so` after installing clang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSX uses `.dylib` for shared libraries, not `.so`.

With Xcode installed, I can find it with:

```
 $ find /Applications/Xcode.app -name libclang.dylib
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib
```

Given it's in Xcode's default library directory, you should be able to link it in simply using `-lclang` if you use the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: Yes, I can find it follow your instructions. I'm still a little confused though. As there is clang installed with Xcode, together with the clang installed myself, there is **two** `clang`  coexisting on my mac? I feel that would be a mess. How should I manage them? Delete the latter one?

Comment: Unless you need features not offered by the Xcode version, then I would remove the one you added.  It will always be much easier to manage libraries etc simply by installing Xcode.